# need assistance with question about counting and setting

Tags: python

question says:
"Your program should allow the user to enter new ingredients they have bought, and also let them know what is already in their fridge.

It should ask the user for a command, and keep asking until they enter a blank line.

If the first word of the command is Set, this means the user wants to add new ingredients to iFridge. Set will always be followed by two words: the ingredient (e.g. bananas) and the number they have bought (e.g. 5).

If the first word of the command is Query, this means the user wants to know if the ingredient is already in the fridge and, if so, how many are in the fridge. Query will always be followed by one word, the ingredient. If the ingredient is in the fridge, you should let the user know how many they have. If the ingredient is not in the fridge, you should tell the user that you have no information about that ingredient."

This is what ive got so far:

```
count = []
command = input('Command: ')

a = command.count(command)
b = 0
c = 0

while command:
 count.append(command)
 command = input('Command: ')
 if command in count:
   b = b + 1
 else:
   c = c + 1

count.sort()
print('You named',c,'character(s).')
print('You repeated',b,'time(s).')
```

my code pretty much doesnt do anything

this is what i should be able to do:

```
Command: Set bananas 6
Command: Set corn 3
Command: Query butter
I have no information about butter.
Command: Query bananas
You have 6 bananas.
Command: Set cucumbers 2
Command:
```

only Set and Query are allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start thinking about what you need to do. You need to

- Parse a command: Check if it is `Set` or `Query`
- Parse the arguments: If the value is `Set` read two items, for `Query` read 1
- Store a value: Save a key:value pair, of `ingredient:quantity`
- Retrieve a value: Given a key get a value, find `quantity` for `ingredient`

For the first part of the problem you'll just need to do a string match and call an appropriate method to handle the request. You'll need to make this method.

In the method you can then parse the rest of the arguments. It will be slightly different in `Set` than it is for `Query`

For storing the values I would use a dictionary. This is one of the basic data structures built into python:

```
ingredients = {}
ingredients['banana'] = 6
```

For getting the values, just query the the dictionary:

```
print(ingredients['banana'])
```

I leave the rest up to you.